# what is the best way to mark any text?

Tags: text, markup

I need users to mark some section of text with custom tags, I can't use the xml based tags as the whole text will be embedded in XML documents and all the < will be converted to html escape code <. I want users to marks some section of text with tags like skip, bookmark, these tags can have attributes also like bookmark name="first".
Which is the best way of allowing users to mark text using the BB forum way like [b]abcd[/b]
or using {{bookmark name="first"}}.
Or is there any better scheme or technique available.

I don't want to change the structure of the text as down by the markdown or textile, I just want to tag some section of text, like the phpBB tags. The question is there any other style than phpBB? Like in some software I see {{bookmark name = "abcd"}} style.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. Do you just want a description of a markup style? Do you want software of some kind? Why not just do it any way you want?

Comment: I am not looking for any software, but I am writing a software where users inputs some text which will be embedded into some XML. Users marks the text with some tags which need to be parsed programmatically and convert to corresponding XML. Which is the best way to allow users to mark some text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The three common markups I know of for this purpose are [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) (used, I believe, by SO), [textile](http://www.textism.com/tools/textile/), and [BBCode](http://pear.php.net/pepr/pepr-bbcode-help.php). The first two are commonly used for blog sites and CMS frameworks, and BBCode I think is usually associated with bulletin-board sites. Preview and mapping utilities are available for each.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at the [Textile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Textile_(markup_language)) markup language to see if it fits your needs. It has many implementations and nice [documentation](http://hobix.com/textile/).